# how to desing as follows in the image on android

Tags: android-layout, android

How to design the following image in android using relative layout. i did design like but it is not like the image and i do not know how to draw vertical and horizontal separator. it is nothing but the android call log screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gives this result:
[image: screenshot]
Could use some tweaking, but the basics are there.

- The separators are `View` objects with a width (or height, depending
  on orientation) of 1px.
- The small green arrow (here represented by
  a square) is a `Compound Drawable` belonging to the `TextView` displaying the
  number.

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>     <TextView 
>         android:id="@+id/number"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/smallsquare"
>         android:drawablePadding="8dp"
>         android:text="1-234-567-890"
>         android:textColor="#FFFF"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold"/>
>     <TextView 
>         android:id="@+id/time"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_margin="3dp"
>         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/separator_vert"
>         android:text="13 mins ago"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/number"/>
>     <View 
>         android:id="@+id/separator_vert"
>         android:layout_width="1px"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         android:layout_margin="2dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/phoneicon"
>         android:layout_above="@+id/separator_horz"
>         android:background="#FFAAAAAA"/>
>     <View 
>         android:id="@+id/separator_horz"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="1px"       android:layout_margin="2dp"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/time"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:background="#FFAAAAAA"/>
>     <ImageView 
>         android:id="@+id/phoneicon"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_margin="5dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/mediumsquare"/> </RelativeLayout>
> ```